# toString method in java how to

Tags: java

Ok, I'm finished with my Java code and my teacher wants me to implement a toString() method as stated below

You are to provide a toString method in your GuessLogic  class that returns the state of the GuessLogic  object (that is, all of its member variables) as a single string.

I created the GuessLogic class as

```
int GuessLogic;
GuessLogic = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
```

And then I try to System.out.println(GuessLogic.toString()) because that's how I thought it worked but clearly i'm not understanding something. Very many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a class.  This is a variable.

Comment: I can post the entire code if need be if what I'm asking for is unclear

Comment: After you create a class, you can use your IDE to generate a `toString()` method.

Comment: I don't think it's unclear, it's just wrong.  Do you have the line `class GuessLogic {` in your code?

Comment: @Serph: What you're asking for is pretty clear, you want to implement a method called `.toString()` on a class.  But in order to do that you'll need *a class* first.

Comment: Oh gez I'm stupid lmao ok I understand my problem now. This flu is reeking havoc on my thought process.

Comment: Just a hint: the Java coding conventions state that variable names should start with a lower case character and class names with an upper case character. If you try to stick to them you'll get used to names like `GuessLogic` denoting a class and `guessLogic` denoting a variable. Getting used to this should help you spot that kind of error, i.e. if you have code like yours above it should raise an alarm in your head.

Comment: What you have done here is use a class name as a variable name. This code has no relevance to your class

Answer (score 0):

`int GuessLogic` is a primitive type, not an object, so it hasn't any methods. You should use Integer object or Integer.toString static method

```
Integer.toString(GuessLogic)
```

Comment: "You are to provide a toString method in your GuessLogic class"

Answer (score 0):

I find what you're asking a bit vague, but if you need a toString method for a class you could try and make something like this example for my Photo class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Photo{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", user_id=" + user_id +
            ", imageable_type='" + imageable_type + '\'' +
            ", imageable_id=" + imageable_id +
            ", image_path='" + image_path + '\'' +
            ", description='" + description + '\'' +
            ", metadata='" + metadata + '\'' +
            ", wind='" + wind + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GuessLogic
{
    int value;

    public void setValue(){
        value = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return Integer.toString(value);
    }
}


GuessLogic guessLogic = new GuessLogic()
guessLogic.setValue();
String result = guessLogic.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just defined a variable and it's from the type `int` which is primitive type so you can call a `toString()` nor build methods for it.

To define a class you have to do something like this:

```
public class GuessLogic {
    private int guessLogicVariable;

    public GuessLogic(int guessLogicVariable) {

        this.guessLogicVariable = guessLogicVariable;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "GuessLogic{" +
                "guessLogicVariable=" + guessLogicVariable +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Then you can use that class in a main method or wherever you need it like this:

```
    public final void  main(String args[]){

        GuessLogic guessLogic = new GuessLogic(10);
        System.out.println(guessLogic.toString());
    }
```